# Can you "wait" in Imbroglio?

Tags: imbroglio

Can you wait a turn in Imbroglio without moving or do you always have to move or attack?

If not, is there any way to simulate waiting via a tile power or movement strategy? For example, I noticed that if you block the door when a new monster first peeks out, they effectively lose their turn (they don't move out or attack) and you end up next to them, which is usually what I want.

Comment: Need an "imbroglio" tag, too.

Comment: Done. Tag added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no explicit `Wait`, you can, in limited situations, get the same effect (you don't move, but the enemy does). For example:

- Using a Rune power generally takes a turn. You need Runes to spend. This doesn't apply to a Rune power like Masina's where it simply auto-activates (extra damage) during your turn.
- Using a ranged weapon will attack the enemy, the character doesn't move, but the enemy still moves.
- Entering the tile in front of a gate when the monster is just peeking out. The character moves into the space, but the monster does not get to act. This is kind of a reverse wait, where you force the monster to wait.
- Attacking another enemy will keep you still and cause all other enemies to move. If you're stuck 2 tiles away from a monster, you might walk around until another appears (although, you have to hope or work to get this new monster in the right position).

The developer briefly mentions ["zugzwang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugzwang) in this design post:

> Simultaneously I was thinking about other design problems; the concern that people would find one "best" board and have no reason to play different setups, also the question of whether there needed to be more ways to deal with bad/unfair situations in the game - a panic "bomb" for when too many enemies surround you, or even whether to include a "wait" button to deal with zugzwang (possibly a limited-use effect like 868-HACK's .wait prog).

https://mightyvision.blogspot.com/2016/06/imbroglio-notes-5-imbroglio-friends.html